# How to Clear recently viewed items (frontend user function) - Magento

Tags: magento

Currently in the Magento cart there is a link button that clears the cart of its contents.

In a similar manner, I need to have a link button in the "Recently Viewed" panel that clears a user's recently viewed products list. I'm suspecting this needs to occur by somehow clearing the user's visitation cache - I'm unsure how Magento records and stores visited products.

Does anyone know of a way to do this in Magento?
If anyone has any suggestions on how I may do this, I'd be grateful.

(note this is not a question on how to clear the overall cache in the Magento admin)

Comment: Now edited to provide more info about my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

Recently viewed products data are stored in `report_viewed_product_index` table.

you can delete these records based on `customer_id/visitor_id`

Comment: Do you mean delete them via a SQL query?

Comment: +1 deleted using product id from report_viewed_product_inde and the product isn't showing now in upsell. Magento 2.2.5